# rewrite rule deppend form request domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one repository for 2 instances code: `domain.com` and `api.domain.com`.

What should the rules look like for:

Serving another `robots.txt` file for the `api.doamin.com` domain

For the domain `api.domain.com`, blocking of traffic other than to `api.domain.com/api/` (`/api/` allowed, `/resources/`, ... disallowed or redirected to main domain)

Edit 1: (.htaccess after suggested changes)

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

Redirect "/f/" "/assets/"

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =api.domain.com
RewriteRule !^api/ [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ index.php/image404/index/?r=%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`robots.txt` doesn't really block all web requests, it just instructs crawlers to not to crawl through certain paths.

Better to use `mod_rewrite` rules for this blocking like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =api.doamin.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This rule will block all the traffic for `api.doamin.com` domain that is not going to `/api/` path.

**Note that** this will give 403 for `http://api.domain.com/` as well.

If you need other settings independent from rewrite, use:

```
SetEnvIf HOST ^api.domain.com$  API_SITE
AddType application/x-httpd-php70 .php ENV=API_SITE
```

For having a separate directive in `robots.txt` for `api` domain place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =api.doamin.com
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-api.txt [L,NC]
```

This will rewrite requests for `/robots.txt` to `robots-api.txt` for `api` domain.

Now create a new file called `robots-api.txt` with this content:

```
Disallow: /
```

Comment: I know about `robots.txt` but on api I want different content (Disallow all)

Comment: don't work, return `500 server error` (I update question), (tested on api. When I pasate wrong domain I don't have 500 error (and don't work :) ))

Comment: Oh sorry for the typo. It is fixed now. Also added a change for custom `robots.txt`

Comment: Better. Now I have 403 for all queries. Could the reason be that these are not real paths? (All is rewrites to index.php)

Comment: Change `[F]` to `[L,R=404]`